# Algorithm to remove duplicated location on list

Tags: algorithm, journey

I have a service to find journey and remove the duplicated visit city.

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
        List<List<String>> allPaths = new ArrayList<>();
        allPaths.add(List.of("Newyork","Washington","Los Angeles","Chicago"));
        allPaths.add(List.of("Newyork","Washington","Houston"));
        allPaths.add(List.of("Newyork","Dallas"));
        allPaths.add(List.of("Newyork","Columbus", "Chicago"));
        Set<String> orphanageLocations = new HashSet<>();
        removeDuplicatedLocation(allPaths, orphanageLocations);
        //expected allPaths:
        //"Newyork","Washington","Los Angeles","Chicago"
        //"Newyork","Dallas"
        //"Newyork","Columbus"
        
        //expected orphanageLocations
        //"Houston"
        
    }
    
    private static void removeDuplicatedLocation(List<List<String>> allPaths, Set<String> orphanageLocations){
        //do something here
    }
```

in the `allPaths` i store all the path from a `origin` to other cities.
but may be some path will contain same city, like `Washington` appear in both first and second path.

Now i need a service to remove that duplicated city. when two paths has same city then we take the path which going to more city.

And service also return city that can not visit. for example the 2nd path has "Washington" is duplicated with 1st path, then we remove that 2nd path (it has less city than first one), then there are no path to "Houston" available -> becoming orphanage

Other test cases:

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
        List<List<String>> allPaths = new ArrayList<>();
        allPaths.add(List.of("Newyork","Washington","Los Angeles","Chicago", "Dallas"));
        allPaths.add(List.of("Newyork","Los Angeles","Houston", "Philadenphia"));
        allPaths.add(List.of("Newyork","Dallas"));
        allPaths.add(List.of("Newyork","Columbus", "San Francisco"));
        Set<String> orphanageLocations = new HashSet<>();
        removeDuplicatedLocation(allPaths, orphanageLocations);
        //expected allPaths:
        //"Newyork","Washington","Los Angeles","Chicago", "Dallas"
        //"Newyork","Columbus", "San Francisco"
        
        //expected orphanageLocations
        //"Houston","Philadenphia"
        
    }
```

Would somebody suggest me a algorithm to solve it?

---Edit 1: i update my dirty solution here, still waiting for better one

```java
private static void removeDuplicatedLocation(List<List<String>> allPaths, Set<String> orphanageLocations){
        //sort to make sure the longest path is on top
        List<List<String>> sortedPaths = allPaths.stream().sorted((a, b) -> Integer.compare(b.size(), a.size()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        for(int i = 0; i < sortedPaths.size()-1; i++){
            List<String> path = sortedPaths.get(i);
            orphanageLocations.removeIf(path::contains);
            for(int j = i+1; j < sortedPaths.size(); j++){
                for(int k = 1; k < path.size();k++) {
                    Iterator<String> iterator = sortedPaths.get(j).iterator();
                    boolean isRemove = false;
                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        String city = iterator.next();
                        if(isRemove && !path.contains(city)){
                            orphanageLocations.add(city);
                        }
                        if(StringUtils.equals(city, path.get(k))){
                            isRemove = true;
                        }
                        if(isRemove){
                            iterator.remove();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //remove path if it's only origin
        sortedPaths.removeIf(item -> item.size() == 1);
        allPaths.clear();
        allPaths.addAll(sortedPaths);
    }
```

---Edit 2: Thanks for solution of @devReddit, i made a small test with huge amount of route.
The more city in each path, the slower your solution is

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
        List<List<String>> allPaths = new ArrayList<>();
        List<List<String>> allPaths2 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> locations = Stream.of("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N",
                                        "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "X", "Y", "Z").collect(Collectors.toList());
        Random rand = new Random();
        int numberOfRoute = 10000;
        String origin = "NY";
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfRoute; i++){
            List<String> route = new ArrayList<>();
            List<String> route2 = new ArrayList<>();
            route.add(origin);
            route2.add(origin);
            //int routeLength = rand.nextInt(locations.size());
            int routeLength = 10;
            while(route.size() < routeLength){
                int randomIndex = rand.nextInt(locations.size()-1);
                if(!route.contains(locations.get(randomIndex))){
                    route.add(locations.get(randomIndex));
                    route2.add(locations.get(randomIndex));
                }
            }
            allPaths.add(route);
            allPaths2.add(route2);
        }

        System.out.println("Process for " + allPaths2.size() + " routes");
        Set<String> orphanageLocations2 = new HashSet<>();
        long startTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        removeDuplicatedLocation3(allPaths2, orphanageLocations2); //uncle bob solution
        long endTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(allPaths2);
        System.out.println(orphanageLocations2);
        System.out.println("Total time uncleBob solution(ms):" + (endTime2-startTime2));

        System.out.println("Process for " + allPaths.size() + " routes");
        Set<String> orphanageLocations = new HashSet<>();
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        removeDuplicatedLocation(allPaths, orphanageLocations); //devReddit solution
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(allPaths);
        System.out.println(orphanageLocations);
        System.out.println("Total time devReddit solution(ms):" + (endTime-startTime));
}

//devReddit solution
private static void removeDuplicatedLocation(List<List<String>> allPaths, Set<String> orphanageLocations) {
        List<List<String>> sortedFixedPaths = allPaths                  // List.of produces immutable lists,
                .stream()                                               // so you can't directly remove string from the list
                .sorted((a, b) -> Integer.compare(b.size(), a.size()))  // this fixed list will be needed later
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<List<String>> sortedPaths = sortedFixedPaths              // The list is regenerated through manual deep copy
                .stream()                                              // generated a single string from the streams of
                .map(path ->                                           // each List<String> and created new list, this is now mutable
                        new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(String.join(",", path).split(","))))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        Set<List<String>> valuesToBeRemoved = new HashSet<>();
        String source = sortedPaths.get(0).get(0);
        Map<String, List<Integer>> cityMapOfIndex = generateHashMap(sortedPaths, source);    // This hashmap keeps track of the existence of cities in different lists
        removeDuplicates(cityMapOfIndex, sortedPaths);                 // this method removes the duplicates from the smaller paths
        // adds the remaining cities to orphanList
        cityMapOfIndex.forEach((cityName, value) -> {           // this block checks whether any mid element in the path is gone
            int index = value.get(0);                        // removes the path from result list
            List<String> list = sortedPaths.get(index);
            int indexInPath = list.indexOf(cityName);
            if (indexInPath != sortedFixedPaths.get(index).indexOf(cityName)) {
                orphanageLocations.add(cityName);
                sortedPaths.get(index).remove(indexInPath);
            }
        });
        valuesToBeRemoved.add(new ArrayList<>(Collections.singleton(source)));   // To handle the case where only source remains in the path
        sortedPaths.removeAll(valuesToBeRemoved);                                 // after removing other duplicates
        allPaths.clear();
        allPaths.addAll(sortedPaths);
    }

    private static void removeDuplicates(Map<String, List<Integer>> cityMapOfIndex, List<List<String>> sortedPaths) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry : cityMapOfIndex.entrySet()) {
            List<Integer> indexList = entry.getValue();
            while (indexList.size() > 1) {
                int index = indexList.get(indexList.size() - 1);         // get the last index i.e. the smallest list of city where this entry exists
                sortedPaths.get(index).remove(entry.getKey());          // remove the city from the list
                indexList.remove((Integer) index);                // update the index list of occurrence
            }
            cityMapOfIndex.put(entry.getKey(), indexList);
        }
    }

    private static Map<String, List<Integer>> generateHashMap(List<List<String>> sortedPaths,
                                                              String source) {
        Map<String, List<Integer>> cityMapOfIndex = new HashMap<>();
        for (int x = 0; x < sortedPaths.size(); x++) {
            int finalX = x;
            sortedPaths.get(x)
                    .forEach(city -> {
                        if (!city.equalsIgnoreCase(source)) {                   // add entries for all except the source
                            List<Integer> indexList = cityMapOfIndex.containsKey(city) ?         // checks whether there's already an entry
                                    cityMapOfIndex.get(city) : new ArrayList<>();                // to avoid data loss due to overwriting
                            indexList.add(finalX);                                    // adds the index of the List of string
                            cityMapOfIndex.put(city, indexList);               // add or update the map with current indexList
                        }
                    });

        }
        return cityMapOfIndex;
    }

//Bob solution
private static void removeDuplicatedLocation3(List<List<String>> allPaths, Set<String> orphanageLocations){
        //sort to make sure the longest path is on top
        List<List<String>> sortedPaths = allPaths.stream().sorted((a, b) -> Integer.compare(b.size(), a.size()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        for(int i = 0; i < sortedPaths.size()-1; i++){
            List<String> path = sortedPaths.get(i);
            orphanageLocations.removeIf(path::contains);
            for(int j = i+1; j < sortedPaths.size(); j++){
                for(int k = 1; k < path.size();k++) {
                    Iterator<String> iterator = sortedPaths.get(j).iterator();
                    boolean isRemove = false;
                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        String city = iterator.next();
                        if(isRemove && !path.contains(city)){
                            orphanageLocations.add(city);
                        }
                        if(StringUtils.equals(city, path.get(k))){
                            isRemove = true;
                        }
                        if(isRemove){
                            iterator.remove();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //remove path if it's only origin
        sortedPaths.removeIf(item -> item.size() == 1);
        allPaths.clear();
        allPaths.addAll(sortedPaths);
    }
```

Here is one of the result:

Test with route lenth is 6

```
Process for 10000 routes
[[NY, Q, Y, T, S, X], [NY, E], [NY, V, A, H, N], [NY, J, L, I], [NY, D], [NY, O], [NY, C], [NY, P, M], [NY, F], [NY, K], [NY, U], [NY, G], [NY, R], [NY, B]]
[]
Total time uncleBob solution(ms):326
Process for 10000 routes
[[NY, Q, Y, T, S, X], [NY, E], [NY, V], [NY, J, L], [NY, D], [NY, O]]
[A, B, C, F, G, H, I, K, M, N, P, R, U]
Total time devReddit solution(ms):206
```

With route length is 10

```
Process for 10000 routes
[[NY, J, V, G, A, I, B, R, U, S], [NY, L, X, Q, M, E], [NY, K], [NY, Y], [NY, F, P], [NY, N], [NY, H, D], [NY, T, O], [NY, C]]
[]
Total time uncleBob solution(ms):292
Process for 10000 routes
[[NY, J, V, G, A, I, B, R, U, S]]
[C, D, E, F, H, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, T, X, Y]
Total time devReddit solution(ms):471
```

Also result is not the same,from the same inpit, mine return more valid route

Actually i this is not what i expect because solution from @devReddit look better & faster

Thanks

Comment: You need to cover more cases in your explanation Newyork, ... ,Washington and Newyork, Washington are not same paths, correct?

Comment: hi @4EACH yes, not same path. for sure no same path here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your provided solution is `O(m^2xn^2)`. I've figured out a solution which has `O(n^2)` time complexity. Necessary comments have been added as explanation:

The core method `removeDuplicatedLocation`:

```java
private static void removeDuplicatedLocation(List<List<String>> allPaths, Set<String> orphanageLocations) {
    List<List<String>> sortedFixedPaths = allPaths                  // List.of produces immutable lists,
            .stream()                                               // so you can't directly remove string from the list
            .sorted((a, b) -> Integer.compare(b.size(), a.size()))  // this fixed list will be needed later
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<List<String>> sortedPaths = sortedFixedPaths              // The list is regenerated through manual deep copy
            .stream()                                              // generated a single string from the streams of
            .map(path ->                                           // each List<String> and created new list, this is now mutable
                    new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(String.join(",", path).split(","))))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    Set<List<String>> valuesToBeRemoved = new HashSet<>();
    String source = sortedPaths.get(0).get(0);
    Map<String, List<Integer>> cityMapOfIndex = generateHashMap(sortedPaths, source);    // This hashmap keeps track of the existence of cities in different lists
    removeDuplicates(cityMapOfIndex, sortedPaths);                 // this method removes the duplicates from the smaller paths
    cityMapOfIndex.entrySet().stream().forEach(city -> {           // this block checks whether any mid element in the path is gone
        String cityName = city.getKey();                           // adds the remaining cities to orphanList
        int index = city.getValue().get(0);                        // removes the path from result list
        List<String> list = sortedPaths.get(index);
        int indexInPath = list.indexOf(cityName);
        if (indexInPath != sortedFixedPaths.get(index).indexOf(cityName)) {
            orphanageLocations.add(cityName);
            sortedPaths.get(index).remove(indexInPath);
        }
    });
    valuesToBeRemoved.add(new ArrayList<>(Collections.singleton(source)));   // To handle the case where only source remains in the path
    sortedPaths.removeAll(valuesToBeRemoved);                                 // after removing other duplicates
    allPaths.clear();
    allPaths.addAll(sortedPaths);
}
```

The `removeDuplicates` and `generateHashMap` methods used in the aforementioned stub is given below:

```java
private static void removeDuplicates(Map<String, List<Integer>> cityMapOfIndex, List<List<String>> sortedPaths) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry : cityMapOfIndex.entrySet()) {
        List<Integer> indexList = entry.getValue();
        while (indexList.size() > 1) {
            int index = indexList.get(indexList.size() - 1);         // get the last index i.e. the smallest list of city where this entry exists
            sortedPaths.get(index).remove(entry.getKey());          // remove the city from the list
            indexList.remove((Integer) index);                // update the index list of occurrence
        }
        cityMapOfIndex.put(entry.getKey(), indexList);
    }
}

private static Map<String, List<Integer>> generateHashMap(List<List<String>> sortedPaths,
                                                          String source) {
    Map<String, List<Integer>> cityMapOfIndex = new HashMap<>();
    for (int x = 0; x < sortedPaths.size(); x++) {     
        int finalX = x;
        sortedPaths.get(x)
                .stream()
                .forEach(city -> {
                    if (!city.equalsIgnoreCase(source)) {                   // add entries for all except the source
                        List<Integer> indexList = cityMapOfIndex.containsKey(city) ?         // checks whether there's already an entry
                                cityMapOfIndex.get(city) : new ArrayList<>();                // to avoid data loss due to overwriting
                        indexList.add(finalX);                                    // adds the index of the List of string
                        cityMapOfIndex.put(city, indexList);               // add or update the map with current indexList
                    }
                });
    }
    return cityMapOfIndex;
}
```

Please let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Thanks @devReddit, your solution work well. i got your idea. this is must faster than mine. just wonder why you use peek(...).collect() instead of just forEach()? i replace it and still work well

Comment: @unclebob oh! my bad, was using that for another purpose, forgot to replace that thing. Please switch to forEach() as using `peek` is risky if there's no terminal operation guaranteed or can be changed. I'm updating the answer with foreach.

Comment: I found small issue with this solution, input: ["Newyork","Washington","Los Angeles","Chicago", "Alaska"], ["Newyork","Columbus", "Chicago"],["Newyork","Washington","Houston"],["Newyork","Cali","Washington", "Texas"]

Comment: i expect result ["Newyork","Washington","Los Angeles","Chicago", "Alaska"], ["Newyork","Columbus"],["Newyork","Cali"]

Comment: [Newyork,Cali] is still valid route. cc @devReddit

Comment: @unclebob I've found the bug, will soon update the answer and inform you here.

Comment: @unclebob the issue was in this line: `valuesToBeRemoved.add(list);` in the `removeDuplicatedLocation` method. However it is fixed replacing the line with: `sortedPaths.get(index).remove(indexInPath);` Please check now.

Comment: ah yeah, it works perfectly now. basically the `valuesToBeRemoved` will only remain origin

Comment: Yeah, the values to be removed will be used only when there will remain the source

Comment: hi @devReddit, i've just updated my test case with your solution in question, could you take a look and try again in your IDE?

Comment: @unclebob your solution has bug, observe the resulted routes and the orphanage locations, you'll understand.

Comment: thanks @devReddit, i checked and fixed issue. but look like your solution will also remove the path if it remain only 2 items. i updated new result on question part.